# Using git and svn both as shared repositories

Tags: git-svn

We have multiple teams working on a common svn repository. Is there a way to have one of the teams to work on git and other teams continue using svn.

What I like to do is have a shared (central) git repository for one of the "GIT" team (multiple developers). The "GIT" team Developers clone from shared git repository to dev. machines and push changes to shared git repository.

Merge the changes from shared Git repository to SVN periodically.(we could call this as promoting code to central SVN repository).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) should let you set that up just fine.  You may want to move the question to `superuser` as it's not really something you have to *program* after all;-)